# Make the browser open links with authorization header

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, jwt, token

I can use JavaScript to construct custom requests using my token, jQuery example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/page",
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}
});
```

To get the page at `/page` which may require authentication to do.

But what if I have in my page a link

```
<a href="/page"></a>
```

The user is *already*  authenticated, there is a token in `localStorage`.

How can I set it up so that clicking on the link loads a new webpage as usual, but tell the server `Authorization: Bearer ...` in the header of that request so the server knows the request is authentic?

Comment: It is very inadvisable to store bearer tokens in localStorage unless the payload is encrypted.  Any authentication your application requires can be bypassed by a user with local privileges to the machine on which the data is stored.  It's also susceptible to theft by cross-site scripting.

Use sessionStorage instead. It's only available to that window/tab, and it is destroyed when the window/tab is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify headers in browser navigation. If you need to authenticate when the user visits the page, you should create a cookie.

Cookies get sent in all requests. Storing your authentication token there would do what you need.

Comment: I've read cookies are vulnerable to XSS and CSRF. Why do all the JWT tutorials say not to use a Cookie?

Comment: Because JWT's are intended to use for an API. Frontend fetches data from the API using its JWT.

You can still use cookies and prevent them from being insecure. If you need authentication on navigation, JWT is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Cookies, like I said. Cookies are still very secure, simply it is easy to be careless with them; resulting in those vulnerabilities you mentioned.

Comment: @minseong Simply you can fix those vulnerabilities by following best practices like `Domain Control`, `Mark as Secured` and more...

Comment: `JWT` also has vulnerabilities.
https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/